# Pulling all data from two tables, single row from third?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have three tables called "Users", "Bridge" and "Cards":

```
| ID | FirstName  | LastName |
|----|------------|----------|
| 1  | David      | Gray     |
| 2  | John       | Smith    |

| ID | CardNumber |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 101        |
| 2  | 102        |

| CardNumber | Value |
|------------|-------|
| 101        | ABC   |
| 101        | 1600  |
| 101        | 1700  |
| 101        | 1800  |
| 102        | DEF   |
| 102        | 1699  |
| 102        | 1799  |
| 102        | 1899  |
```

I'm trying to write a query that does the following:

Select **FirstName** and **LastName** from Table 1, **CardNumber** from Table 2, and **Value** from Table 3, BUT I only want the single highest **number** for each user (side note: I'm happy to grab CardNumber from Cards, as long as it matches up)

So my query would return

```
David, Gray, 101, 1800
John, Smith, 102, 1899
```

But I can't work out how to do it in MS-SQL. Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
 Users.ID, 
 Users.FirstName, 
 Users.LastName,
 Bridge.CardNumber,
 Cards.Value
FROM Users
 LEFT JOIN Bridge ON Users.ID = Bridge.ID
 LEFT JOIN Cards ON Bridge.CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber
WHERE
 Cards.Value = (SELECT Cards.Value FROM Cards ORDER BY Cards.Value DESC)
```

Which returns a single user, not all users. Dropping the `WHERE` clause returns all users as I'd expect, but I'm not sure how to get the middle ground.

I've created an [SQLite fiddle here](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58a27a963315a99ef70194aede33b07847a9d21e479ac41800), which is close enough (I can switch flavours from there)

What can I do from here?

Comment: Is value can be ABC? Def?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza: No, it needs to be a number, because the results end up printed on a magnetic stripe that only accepts numbers

Answer (score 1):

Check This.
Simple Solution with Group by and max() function.

```
  SELECT 
   Users.ID, 
   Users.FirstName, 
   Users.LastName,
   Bridge.CardNumber,
   MAX(cast(Cards.Value as int))
  FROM Users
   LEFT JOIN Bridge ON Users.ID = Bridge.Id
   LEFT JOIN Cards ON Bridge.CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber  
  GROUP BY 
   Users.ID, 
   Users.FirstName, 
   Users.LastName,
   Bridge.CardNumber
```

[SQLite fiddle here,](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58a2862d85650b2f5aa72adf15654520c2ea0c5d99dfc91151)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select t1.ID,t1.FirstName,t1.LastName,t2.CardNumber,
max(cast(t3.Value as int)) as [MaxValue] 
from tblUsers t1 
inner join tblBridge t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
inner join tblCards t3 on t2.CardNumber=t3.CardNumber
where isnumeric(t3.Value)=1    
group by t1.ID,t1.FirstName,t1.LastName,t2.CardNumber
```

Beacuse each itteration of join query calculate max value from Cards table and bind with query.

Comment: Now my query has been updated with "where isnumeric(t3.Value)=1" for check   "101        | ABC"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from (
    select Users.ID,
        Users.FirstName,
        Users.LastName,
        Bridge.CardNumber,
        Cards.Value,
        row_number() over (
            partition by Users.id order by convert(int, Cards.value) desc
            ) rn
    from Users
    left join Bridge on Users.ID = Bridge.ID
    left join Cards on Bridge.CardNumber = Cards.CardNumber
        and Cards.Value not like '%[^0-9]%'
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take `MAX(value)` and remaining in `Group BY`

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #USERS( ID  INT,FirstName   VARCHAR(50),LastName VARCHAR(50))
 INSERT INTO #USERS
SELECT 1,   'David' ,      'Gray'   
UNION ALL  
SELECT 2,   'John'   ,     'Smith'    

CREATE TABLE #BRIDGE( ID INT,  CardNumber VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #BRIDGE

SELECT 1 ,  101        
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,  102        

CREATE TABLE #CARDS( CardNumber VARCHAR(50), Value INT)

INSERT INTO #CARDS
SELECT 101,         '1000' 
UNION ALL  
SELECT 101 ,        '1600'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 101 ,        '1700'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 101 ,        '1800'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 102 ,        '800'   
UNION ALL
SELECT 102 ,        '1699'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 102 ,        '1799'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 102 ,        '1899'
```

per the comment

> No, it needs to be a number,

```
SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, B.CardNumber,MAX( C.Value )
FROM #USERS U
INNER JOIN #BRIDGE B ON U.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN #CARDS C ON B.CardNumber = C.CardNumber
GROUP BY  U.FirstName, U.LastName, B.CardNumber
```

If the Value is of type varchar and having values like ABC and you want to exclude them..

```
SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, B.CardNumber,MAX(CAST( C.Value AS INT)  )
FROM #USERS U
INNER JOIN #BRIDGE B ON U.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN #CARDS C ON B.CardNumber = C.CardNumber
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value)=1
GROUP BY  U.FirstName, U.LastName, B.CardNumber
```

And the result will be

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
| FirstName | LastName | CardNumber | value |
+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
| David     | Gray     |        101 |  1800 |
| John      | Smith    |        102 |  1899 |
+-----------+----------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

using simple sub query we can do in this way also

```
select 
T.FirstName, 
T.LastName,
TT.CardNumber,
TTT.Value 
    from  users T
INNER JOIN Bridge TT
ON T.ID = TT.ID
INNER JOIN (Select MAX(Value) Value ,
                CardNumber 
                            from  Cards 
                                WHERE CardNumber = CardNumber
AND VALUE  LIKE  '%[^A-Za-z]%'
GROUP BY CardNumber) TTT
ON TT.CardNumber = TTT.CardNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. And give a row number for the `Cards` table based on the `Value` column.

**Query**

```
select t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t2.CardNumber, t3.Value
from Users t1
left join Bridge t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
left join (
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by CardNumber 
        order by case when Value like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 2 end,
        len(Value) desc, Value desc
    ), * from Cards) t3
on t2.CardNumber = t3.CardNumber
and t3.[rn] = 1;
```